# Can't create JDBC driver for class ""

Tags: mysql, jsf, jdbc

So I'm stuck with a small problem in a rather large application atm, to which - after x1000 tries, I'm at a loss.

I'm trying to connect to mysql database within a DAO pattern, viewed by a JSF page.

First of all the getConnection part of daoManager:

```
Connection con = null;
DataSource ds;

public Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        InitialContext cxt = new InitialContext();
        ds = (DataSource) cxt.lookup( "java:/comp/env/jdbc/db");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
    return ds.getConnection();
}
```

Now, this should already here be working given the correct driver placement.
I've tried a few things, placing the driver in both the project and in WEB-INF, ofcourse marked as a library:

[image]

Further more I've also included said driver in tomcat/lib.

The context.xml is as follows:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/db" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
          username="******" password="******" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javatest"/>
```

And lastly the web.xml is as follows:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/db</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Now.. The error in the stacktrace is as follows:

**java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'**

**Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver**

If any more info is needed, don't be hesitant to holla at me :)

Comment: context.xml file is at wrong location, JDBC driver JAR file should not be in webapp. See duplicate for correct instructions.

Comment: This is not a jsf question